# Confused about a well-ordering lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I happened to stumble across the following lemma in Kenneth Kunen's set theory book:

$\textbf{Lemma:}$ Let $\langle$ $A,R$ $\rangle$ be a well ordering. Then for all $x \in A$, $\langle$ $A,R$ $\rangle$ is not isomorphic to 
$\hspace {15mm}$ $\langle$ pred$(A,x,R),R$ $\rangle$.

Where $A$ is a set, $R$ is a strict total order on $A$, and pred$(A,x,R)$ = { $y \in A: yRx$ } where $x \in A$.

But then what if we let $A=\mathbb{N}$, $R$ be the standard greater than relation >, and $x=0$?

$A$ would be the set $\{0,1,2......\}$

pred$(A,x,R)$ would be the set $\{1,2,3......\}$

I am pretty that for both sets, > is still a strict total order and every subset has a least element under this order. So couldn't we just set an isomorphism $f: A \rightarrow$ pred$(A,0,R)$ where $f(x)=x+1$?

Sorry if I happen to be incredibly stupid right now but I can't spot my error.

Comment: pred$(A,5,R)$ is $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ which is not $A$. My comment applies to the standard $<$ relation, whereas your question seems to instead work with $>$ but note that $<$ is a well-order on $A$, and $>$ is not a well-order. If you mean $>$ instead of $<$, then $A$ has no "least" element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the set of predecessors are those "smaller" than $x$. So in the case of $\Bbb N$ and $x=1$ this is just $\{0\}$. For $x=0$ it's $\varnothing$. Neither is isomorphic to $\Bbb N$ itself.

If you reverse the order, then it's not a well-ordering anymore, since there is no minimal element.

Comment: Couldn't one define a smallest element $y$ of a set $A$ under > iff $x$ > $y$ for all $x$ in $A$?

Comment: If you look at $\Bbb N$ ordered by $x\lhd y$ if and only if $y$ is *smaller* than $x$, then there is no minimal element. If you consider the *usual* ordering, then $0$ is indeed the minimal element, but the set of predecessors of $0$ is $\varnothing$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ^^